# views didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

I'm implementing some search mechanism on my app, trying to get the query from input, look for it in database(sqlite) and render it to template. Problem is that I'm getting error:

> .views didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Logic is like:
 1) making a function which will check given query

```
def search_query(request,search,query):

    checking = check_in(query) #check if query is in DB

    if checking == False: #if not, get data from search api and save it
        search_querys = requests.get(search)
        json_search = search_querys.json()   
        for each in json_search['data']:    
            user_id = each['id']
            name = each['name']
            picture = each['picture']['data']['url']
            Profiles.objects.create(user_id=user_id, name=name, picture=picture)

        return render(request, 'FB_search/home.html') 

    else:   # <--assuming that here's the problem. For testing purpose, I'm writing query for which I know that they are in DB and I'd like to return in tamplet
        context = {
            'profiles': Profiles.objects.filter(Q(user_id__startswith=query) | Q(name__startswith=query))
        }       

        return render(request, 'FB_search/home.html', context)
```

2) calling function above in my endpoint like:

```
def api_search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
       query = request.GET.get('q')
       search = 'some API with {query} inside it' 
       search_query(request,search,query)
```

When I try to call the "search query" funtion I'm getting mentioned error. 
Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the return value of `search_query`, you should return it:

```
def api_search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
       query = request.GET.get('q')
       search = 'some API with {query} inside it' 
       return search_query(request,search,query)
```